# greendao Left join dilemma

Tags: android, greendao

I'm using greenDao and I need to extract data from several tables similar to left-join funcionality. Here's a cite from my schema generator:

```
private static void genRetailers(Schema schema) {
    // create retailer entity
    Entity retailerEntity = schema.addEntity("Retailer");
    retailerEntity.addIdProperty().notNull();
    retailerEntity.addStringProperty("title");

    Entity shopEntity = schema.addEntity("Shop");
    shopEntity.addIdProperty().notNull();
    shopEntity.addStringProperty("address");
    Property retailerId = shopEntity.addLongProperty("retailerId")
            .getProperty();
    // (1) Retailer < - > (*) Shop
    retailerEntity.addToMany(shopEntity, retailerId);
}
```

When I do:

```
    return (ArrayList<Retailer>) mDaoSession.getRetailerDao()
                .queryBuilder().list();
```

I only get contents of the Retailer table itself, however I also need Shop entity values which're null. Only after I call `getShops()` the entities get filled. I need to fill entities right at the first query. How is it done ?

Thanks.

Comment: You describe how greenDAO is designed to work. Relations are resolved lazily on their first access.What you don't state is what you are trying to achieve and why it cannot be done using standard relations.

Answer (score -1):

Use the queryDeep method:

```
return mDaoSession.getRetailerDao().queryDeep(null);
```

Comment: A little more explanation wouldn't hurt. Also this method doesn't seem to be available anymore.